# Adonis Edge Template throws E_INVALID_EXPRESSION: Invalid expression <undefined> passed to (if) block

Tags: templating, adonis.js

I am trying to do something like this.

```
@each(user in users)
   @if(user.something)
      <h2>something</h2>

   @else
      <h2>something else</h2>
```

Comment: Can you share your data? to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Edge templating engine doesn't support space after any tag, That's what was causing problem.

Comment: Can confirm. `@if (expression)` fails, but `@if(expression)` works. I feel like this should be filed as a bug.